# UICollectionViewCell subview have wrong position (autolayout)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using UICollectionView and subclassed cell. Cell is loaded from a xib where I layout a few subviews. Inside the cell I have a BOOL that change one of the subviews contraint. On iOS this works. But on iOS 7 after the constraint is changed, the position of this subview is wrong. If I logged the info in console, the constraint is set to 0 but the frame show the 188.

I know there is a bug about contentView resizing, and I handle that well with setting autoresizing mask. But what about this problem.

This are the constraints for this subview:
[image: constraints]

So inside the code when the BOOL is set to YES, the topConstraint is set from 0 to (-self.thisSubview.bounds.size.height).

If I log bounds height it tells me that its 130 so the origin.x should be now -130 but its -188 actually.

This is the code where I change the contstaint:

```
- (void)setHasInfo:(BOOL)hasInfo {
    if (hasInfo) {
        self.infoViewTopCon.constant = 0;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    else {
        self.infoViewTopCon.constant = - self.infoView.bounds.size.height + 4.0;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    _hasInfo = hasInfo;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing the constraints.

Comment: leading = superview.leading  trailing = superview.trailing  
height = superview.height
**top = superview.top**

Comment: What's the code where you update the constraints? Please edit it into your question

Answer (score 0):

Update the `NSLayoutConstraints` to make it work.

[image: image1]

Comment: Are you shure. I dont think this will solve this. Probably I wrote my issue to complicated. I check both values inside the code (frame and constraint) and it show different values. I think this wont help me.

Comment: Click on "Edit" next to the constraints and change them to the desired value. Then update the constraints.

Comment: I later update constraints in code when user interact with the cell. So edit constraints in xib wont help. In xib file the constraint work just fine. The issue is when I change one of the constraint in code. The value of constraint and the valu of frame are not synchronised.

Comment: I add it at the bottom of my question.